# Java Encryption: Java Encription: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher

Tags: java, base64, encryption

I have a Java HTTP server which receive messages from a java client.

Both server and client use same Encrypter class:

```
public class Encrypter {

    private Cipher cipher; //The encryption cipher object
public static final String ALGORITHM = "Blowfish"; //Encryption Algorithm

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Encrypter()
    {       
        try {
            initlizeCipher();
        } catch (Throwable e) {     
            ServerSettings.LOG.logError(e);
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the Cipher object
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws NoSuchPaddingException
     */
    private void initlizeCipher() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException
    {       
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ServerSettings.ALGORITHM);
    }

    /**
     * Encrypt a String
     * @param string String to encrypt
     * @return an encrypted String
     * @throws InvalidKeyException
     * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException
     * @throws BadPaddingException
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     */
    public synchronized String encrypt(String string) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, ServerSettings.SECRECT_KEY_SPEC);
        byte[] stringBytes = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(stringBytes);
        return Base64.encodeBytes(encryptedBytes);      
    }

    /**
     * Decrypt a String
     * @param string String to decrypt
     * @return a decrypted String
     * @throws InvalidKeyException
     * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException
     * @throws BadPaddingException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public synchronized String decrypt(String string) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException
    {       
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, ServerSettings.SECRECT_KEY_SPEC);
        byte[] decryptedBytes = Base64.decode(string.getBytes());       
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(decryptedBytes);
        return new String(encryptedBytes,"UTF-8");
    }   
}
```

i'm sending message to server through POST method when the variables being sent are: `m=encryptedMessage.`

from some reason i always get the

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

and i'm not able to decrypt the message received on the server side..

i thought at first that maybe the message is broken but it doesn't..

Any Ideas ?

**UPDATE1:**

The weird thing is that some messages to the server are decrypted properly and some return that error.
Good message:

```
zuhRpmbtH0xSmv6cnBFkAxaGFmRbDP/97LwF4bcDyhANCTLb4afBzFpP3GI1pGFLok03GRQVCwi81Hsp                                             bCpGtuoIVY9cqWYDzNFgOCx5w2sboR2Qx6oxtTSIFIzj1XadQdk9V8lCxcCVVYEH8vA3tph63wU6qJOo                                             OyROz0OJauLBEiWbn5OUQxJ7Yz9Qc1wzl8z7UQb71v4pswF69c1CM/LWWmAzBDCjlRQ5YIB9wN8mBgoC                                             t8Ngt38XkCg/yRHh0EpXYQfrgP6Ls5I8/FY8BQorMy/le5y2
```

Bad message:

```
cjj7yzW v3NDtbIJXurrrf318DcY PBk2inzSfz qoIaTKns2tWvR7ftOKK30XY VAlXDrQlyTLatgKA                                             S4IkAIK3lXQKNcwPh87CybHrTqD3HWEM3tqkpVWdB7GNmpHYsITTLrWsBvaMeDcXEr/gr9KYSZ0ks0gR                                             z12jHxPiZoSKHdy5nZ4zShHUy/wlkslmjFvA1G8A15nTVBhjBI GWSh54tyBZF113lL pm5eZNkZrqzo                                             RWI2QAjfqNPzCpV0tqd/pEO70vdSLbCYi7V0bVQNW2KpBv3Hj3VOTCP92k62/iQhIY4F VuMo2UTgGWV                                             1fqoelrl/eelAvsZO8YNC5/2KTKw2sDFaTOwW9R12AgeyzOuhkKQQro2Umd0KoiGnYL9AaQ6 T2MBnLK                                             ZyROHh3cvI T9chPlGfmUHbCN2f3pHoF5rb383KpJNjvlnmnwtaEhQYw8TQjj4PLenK24Hpcs4 wO8gu                                             XSrUglFzLIkkwjvsA5AyTHx/jP9AwMSnWjDwco184YQGAePeM8PYy42oMOaw7Pg/3jWFy1uOzFok2LN9                                             RJWv1iyXejh5s9zXoAT3kywICQygK2YTLZNIS1d5lc0H0f15EN6itZhaR0YnslhYGmH1KcNwdMWhBKsf                                             PytWnK0N8AzUVzt4P4mtmGSuaLi2t54J2pv7m7/c6WjTi1/E16rd3QyWkmXrghSshOJNRRwcydlhhTLH                                             drHTEFaXSPZyVFqlaFu4 f5kxiBa6ewglKHe6zbmRyM15Mq3lRj8Ab/RWBd2tgvaEO/vhw
```

Both of these message are sent in the same way and are printed to the System.Out for testing.
As u can see the bad message have spaces from some reason while the good message doesn't what probably gives the block error message..
any idea how to solve it ?

**Update 2:**

After digging into my code I've found out that my problem is inside the function that parse the POST method parameters. I can't say i'm an expert in encoding but there is some problem with passing Base64 encoding throw POST URLEcoding..

This is my parsing code which after getting URLDecode goes to my Encrypter for decrypt:

private void parseQuery(String query, HashMap parameters) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

```
 if (query != null) {
     String pairs[] = query.split("[&]");

     for (String pair : pairs) 
     {
         String param[] = pair.split("[=]");
         String key = null;
         String value = null;
         if (param.length > 0) 
             key = URLDecoder.decode(param[0], "UTF-8");//System.getProperty("file.encoding"));                 

         if (param.length > 1) 
             value = URLDecoder.decode(param[1], "UTF-8");//System.getProperty("file.encoding"));                 

         if (parameters.containsKey(key)) 
         {
             Object obj = parameters.get(key);
             if(obj instanceof List<?>)
             {
                 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                 List<String> values = (List<String>)obj;
                 values.add(value);
             } 
             else if(obj instanceof String) 
             {
                 List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
                 values.add((String)obj);
                 values.add(value);
                 parameters.put(key, values);
             }
         } 
         else 
           parameters.put(key, value);                 
     }
 }
```

}

Any Ideas ?

Comment: What is `ServerSettings.ALGORITHM`? Add the actual value for it to your question. Off the cuff though, it looks like you're using a block cipher instead of a stream one.

Comment: The algorithm is Blowfish

Comment: Can you include the full algorithm string? Basically dump the value of `ServerSettings.ALGORITHM` and include it in your question.

Comment: sure, done... added at the beginning

Comment: You never actually say, but is the size of encryptedBytes really a multiple of 8? Perhaps you are loosing something in the decoding or transmission in another layer of the application

Comment: That was what i suspected.. how can i check it?

Comment: @AsafNevo - try your test again, but this time without translating your string bytes to UTF-8 (in both the `encrypt` and `decrypt` methods).

Comment: @Perception i've added an update to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finely  after lots of testing and crying :) , I've found what i was suspecting from the beginning.

When passing data through URL (POST\GET whatever) you must first URL-Encode it first on your client side before sending it, and URL-Decoding on the server side before processing it.

Thanks to Java's great [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) and [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) class you can easily do it:

//Before sending encode your data for URL - Client side
URLEncoder.encode(your_data,charset_name); //charset_name - the recommendation is to use "UTF-8"

//After receiving the data - decode you data for process - Server side
URLDecoder.decode(your_data,charset_name); //charset_name - the recommendation is to use "UTF-8"

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar problem yesterday. I solved it by encoding the bytes to base64 at client side and decoding it before use at the server side.

Refer to this link - [cipher]: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t645364-java-string-encryption-decryption.html

SO basically this is what you need to do -

At client side

- Get the byte array from a string
- Encrypt it.
- Encode the byte array using base64 encoding

At server side

- Decode the base64 encoded data to get a byte array
- Decrypt the byte array.
- Construct a string using this byte array.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but did you read my code? That exactly whats i've done..

Answer (score 0):

To narrow down the alternatives, place download and unlimited strength JCE policy jar from Oracle/Sun and place it under your JVM. from my experience with java cryptography, 90% of the problems you will face when encrypting come from the fact that the JVM/JDK is ship with a strong but limited strength policy and whenever you try to use and 252k or more algorithms, the JVM start throwing some weird errors.